# pre populating dropdown in JSP using jstl

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have a JSTL tag which populates the Age drop down by running from 20 to 60 as below

```
<c:forEach begin="20" end="60" var="i">
   <option value="${i}">${i}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

Now in the Edit mode I want to populate the age with what ever the age is coming from db table

Say the age is 25 then 25 should be selected in age dd.I tried a code but this is not working and showing jspTagexception

```
<c:forEach begin="20" end="60" var="i">
 <option value="${i}" <c:when test ="${User.age == i}">selected</c:when>>${i}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

How to pre populate the age in select dropdown.

Thanks for Reply

[image]

Comment: what exception are you getting?

Comment: I have added the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<c:if test="${User.age == i}"> selected="selected" </c:if>
```

Be sure that you are passing User object to jsp from your controller.

Answer (score 1):

Using wrong tag, when should be used with choose. See this description:

---

The  works like a Java switch statement in that it lets you choose between a number of alternatives. Where the switch statement has case statements, the  tag has  tags. A a switch statement has default clause to specify a default action and similar way  has  as default clause.

---

You can use if like :

```
<c:forEach begin="20" end="60" var="i">
 <option value="${i}" <c:if test ="${User.age == i}">selected</c:if>>${i}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Conditional operator` in there, instead of `<c:when>` tag (which is to used with only `<c:choose>` tag):

```html
<c:forEach begin="20" end="60" var="i">
    <option value="${i}" ${User.age == i ? 'selected' : ''}>${i}</option>
</c:forEach>
```